# Sorting only specific subset of rows in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I spent some time trying to figure out a solution to but haven't been able to figure a simple and clean solution to my problem. Basically I have the following dataframe:

| Plane Parts | Quantity | is_plane |
| --- | --- | --- |
| G6_32 FAB | 1 | True |
| G6_32 KIT | 2 | True |
| Item D | 2 | False |
| Item C | 4 | False |
| Item A | 5 | False |
| G6_32 SITE | 5 | True |
| G6_32 SPACE | 6 | True |
| Item C | 2 | False |
| Item A | 1 | False |
| Item F | 2 | False |

I need to sort only the subset of rows which have `is_plane == False`. So at the end my final result would look like:

| Plane Parts | Quantity | is_plane |
| --- | --- | --- |
| G6_32 FAB | 1 | True |
| G6_32 KIT | 2 | True |
| Item A | 5 | False |
| Item C | 4 | False |
| Item D | 2 | False |
| G6_32 SITE | 5 | True |
| G6_32 SPACE | 6 | True |
| Item A | 1 | False |
| Item C | 2 | False |
| Item F | 2 | False |

Notice that the rows which `is_plane == True` are not supposed to be sorted and kept the original position. Any idea on how to achieve it?

Comment: shouldn't the quantity with 1 be the last row?

Comment: No, the quantities are independent and we shouldn't try to order by it

Comment: ahh so you sort by "Plane Parts"?

Comment: Just to clarify: The column that needs to be sorted is only `Plane Parts` where `is_plane ==False`

Comment: @Paul yes exactly!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

make grouper for grouping

```
grouper = df['is_plane'].ne(df['is_plane'].shift(1)).cumsum()
```

`grouper`:

```
0    1
1    1
2    2
3    2
4    2
5    3
6    3
7    4
8    4
9    4
Name: is_plane, dtype: int32
```

use groupby by grouper

group that its 'Plane Parts' is all False, sort_values by Plane Parts.

```
df.groupby(grouper).apply(lambda x: x.sort_values('Plane Parts') if x['is_plane'].sum() == 0 else x).droplevel(0)
```

output:

```
    Plane Parts Quantity    is_plane
0   G6_32 FAB   1           True
1   G6_32 KIT   2           True
4   Item A      5           False
3   Item C      4           False
2   Item D      2           False
5   G6_32 SITE  5           True
6   G6_32 SPACE 6           True
8   Item A      1           False
7   Item C      2           False
9   Item F      2           False
```